# Search 'Sheet1'!A1 to find any of the values in 'Sheet2'!A:A, and return the matched value

Tags: google-sheets, find, match

I Have used IMPORTXML to pull in a paragraph of text into a cell on google sheets. I need to search this cell to see if it contains any one of a number of values in a given column. If any of these values are found, I want to return the found value.

Comment: what if there is more than one?

Answer (score 0):

#### Answer:

*You can use `FIND` and `MID` formulae to find substrings of certain length from a pre-defined column.*

#### Formula:

In this formula, I have made the following assumptions:

- The column which contains the text to search is column A
- The text imported using `IMPORTXML` is in cell `C9`

Pasting this into cell `B1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(MID(C9, FIND(A1:A,C9),LEN(A1:A)), "Not Found"))
```

**Rundown of this formula:**

- Find in the `IMPORTXML` string the value in the corresponding cell in column `A`
- Find the length of the string in the corresponding cell in column `A`
- Return the substring out of the `IMPORTXML` text in `C9` which starts at the position where the word starts, and has a length equal to that of the string itself
- If the string is found, display the string.
- If the string does not exist, display "Not Found" instead.

#### Visual Example:

[image]

#### References:

- [ARRAYFORMULA function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275?hl=en)
- [IFERROR function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304?hl=en)
- [MID function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129?hl=en)
- [FIND function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094126?hl=en)
- [LEN function - Docs Editors Help](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094081)